# File Manager opens when connected to charger

Tags: charging, astro-file-manager

I am using Sony XPeria with Android 4.0.4. If I connect the device to an AC adapter/charger, the ASTRO File manager opens by default. How to stop the app from opening when the device is connected to the charger?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because the Astro file manager sees it as a connection instead charge only.

When you connect the charger, pull down the top notification menu -> click on the USB icon -> change the settings to "USB charge only"

This should fix it

Comment: No...any option is display notification during file manager is open

Comment: Notification bar is always there on any Android device - just swipe down - picture http://www-static.se-mc.com/blogs.dir/0/files/2011/12/manage-statusbar-notification-panel-xperia-smartphone-PS103.png

Comment: Notification bar is their but no message is there